# Need some help coding a gallery / portfolio

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, gallery, portfolio

I've tried hosting my WIP website to see how it works. Everything goes well except for the following:
On my Portfolio page:
[Portfolio](http://grozav.t15.org/Portfolio.html)

I have coded a "gallery" in jquery.
When the page starts loading it seems that the browser loads the `#portfolioSlider` div which is supposed to be display:none until triggered. It contains lots of images resulting in massive load time until the thumbnails ( `#Portfolio` ) starts loading.

How can I make the `#portfolioSlider` images start loading only after it opens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only to give idea....

```
<div id="galery"><img/></div><script>
var datas={
        "images":[{ 
                    "src":"gallery/panorak.jpg",
                    "title":"PANORAK",
                    "date":"28/10/2010 Web Design",
                    "description":"desc"
                    "id":"panorak"
                    }, 
                    "src":"gallery/panorak.jpg",
                    "title":"PANORAK",
                    "date":"28/10/2010 Web Design",
                    "description":"desc"
                    "id":"panorak"
                    }, 
                ]}
$(document).ready(function(){
var galPlace=$("#galery")

    var list=$("<ul/>");
    galPlace.append(list);
datas.images.each(function(i,j){
    list.prepend($("<li/>").$("<img/>").attr("src",datas.images[i].src).load(function(){ })));
} 
);}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of populating the `src` attribute by default, put the URI of the image in a data attribute. Example:

```
<img src="" data-imageSrc="your/uri/to/image.gif" />
```

Then, when you want to load it, move the data into the src:

```
$('img').attr('src',$(this).data('imageSrc'));
```

Comment: I'd add that this would also allow you to load images in the background.